# enconding issue in dialogflow

Tags: encoding, dialogflow-es

I'm using `DialogFlow` test functionality to call to my webhook  that is on `AWS` (lambda), and I'm getting the next problem:

Example: if my webhook response with this "España", I get this "EspaÃ±a".

I used `Postman` to call this service and  i got the  correct form and in the loggin in my lambda is correctly too.

I've set the webhook headers to be `"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8".`
I'm not sure what other configuration I need to change?

please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript function:

```
encodeURI("España");
```